# How to convert an array of documents to a single specific object in a MongoDB aggregation pipeline

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm building a MongoDB/Mongoose query using the aggregate pipeline in a NodeJS/Express app. I'm trying to take an array of documents and convert it into a single object with the keys as the "_id" fields of each doc, and the values as the entire unedited document itself. I've dug into $group, $unwind, $arrayToObject, etc. and I think I can use a combination of things to get the result I'm looking for, maybe. This is basically what I'm trying to accomplish:

**Take this:**

```
[ 
  { _id: 41, myData: 'blah' }, 
  { _id: 42, myData: 'blah' }, 
  { _id: 43, myData: 'blah' }
]
```

**and convert it to this:**

```
{ 
  41: { _id: 41, myData: 'blah' },
  42: { _id: 42, myData: 'blah' },
  43: { _id: 43, myData: 'blah' }
}
```

Specifically, I don't know how to reference the entire document to add it as a value in a new field. For instance, I was thinking about using `$group` to take each input document and output a new document like this: `{ _id: 42, myData: 'blah' }` --> `{ k: 42, v: { _id: 42, myData: 'blah' } }` and then I could use `$arrayToObject` to create the single object I'm looking for. Maybe there's a better, more performant option.

Comment: Is there specific reason why you want to do this? In MongoDB, using dynamic value as field name is generally considered anti-pattern. On the other hand, depending on your data volume, the final document may exceed [16 MB single document size limit](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-BSON-Document-Size).

Comment: @ray makes some important points.  I would consider them carefully.  But if you really wanted to do this (I wouldn't), here's [one way](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j_FxTXbQ1RW "Link to mongoplayground.net -->").

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thanks! This helps a lot and now I also know about Mongo Playground! Cheers

Comment: @ray This is not for production and I'm trying to match the data requirements I've been given. The amount of data will be small and I'm not planning on saving this data back into Mongo, I'm just trying to optimize this query and send it as a API response. Also I thought this might be useful in some cases to basically 'hashify' a Mongo query before sending it as a response, that way the client can benefit from constant time lookup on that data. But yeah, I would NOT recommend saving a mongo doc this way.